# Python: Compare list with its indices and create a new list

Tags: python, list

In Python, I want to compare a **list of lists** (say **LL1**) with the **indices of its lists** and create another **list of lists** (say **LL2**) in such a manner than LL2 has the **same exact shape** as LL1. As we can see, the list LL1 is **inhomogeneous**. For example:

```
LL1 = [[0, 1, 3, 6, 7], [3, 7], [0, 1, 2, 6, 7], [3], [0, 3, 4, 5, 8]]
LL2 = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1], [2, 2, 2, 2, 2], [3], [4, 4, 4, 4, 4]]
```

I want to achieve this in the **fastest** way possible. Presently, I am using the following method:

```
MP = map(len, LL1)
LL2 = map( lambda x: MP[x]*[x] , range(len(LL1)) )
```

For **large datasets**, the second step is not very fast. Is there a faster alternative to what I am doing? I will really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a list-comprehension to do this in one step:

```
>>> LL1 = [[0, 1, 3, 6, 7], [3, 7], [0, 1, 2, 6, 7], [3], [0, 3, 4, 5, 8]]
>>> LL2 = [[i]*len(sub) for i, sub in enumerate(LL1)]
>>> LL2
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1], [2, 2, 2, 2, 2], [3], [4, 4, 4, 4, 4]]
>>>
```

Another way:

```
>>> LL2 = [[i for _ in range(len(sub))] for i, sub in enumerate(LL1)]
>>> LL2
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1], [2, 2, 2, 2, 2], [3], [4, 4, 4, 4, 4]]
>>>
```

Not sure which is faster...

Comment: @ juanpa.arrivillaga : The first method you proposed is significantly faster than the second one. Thanks for proposing two solutions. But, both these methods are not significantly faster than the method that I am already trying (the one that I have mentioned already in the post.) But again, thanks a ton!

Comment: @SiddTheKid I'm not sure you'll find a faster way, unfortunately.

Comment: I wish I was able to use numpy here. BLAS operations are always faster. But, I don't have a choice with my initial input (LL1),; it is always an inhomogeneous list of lists.

Comment: @SiddTheKid: FYI, if you need `lambda`s to use `map`, `map` is basically guaranteed to be slower than an equivalent listcomp/genexpr that avoids the `lambda`, at least on CPython. The discrepancies are usually not huge, but they're reliable.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Thanks. That's extremely useful information. I'll try to utilize your suggestion in other sections of my code and see if I can get more boosts of speed.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
print([ [LL1.index(i)] * len(i) for i in LL1])
```

Output:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1], [2, 2, 2, 2, 2], [3], [4, 4, 4, 4, 4]]
```

Maybe the above code is not good enough when you got many duplicate elements,so you can try this:

```
print([[i]*len(j) for i,j in enumerate(LL1)])
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is what the OP wanted... one of us is not interpreting it right.

Comment: Strictly speaking, this will not work. Consider `LL1 = [[3, 7], [0, 1, 3, 6, 7], [3, 7], [0, 1, 2, 6, 7], [3], [0, 3, 4, 5, 8]]` Also, it's quadratic time...